# MacFUSE + ext4fuse = No luck

Tags: macos, ext4, fuse, macfuse

So I'm trying to mount my ext4 (with extents) partition on Mac OS X using MacFUSE (from MacPorts) and ext4fuse (compiled from git), but I just can't manage to do it. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
sudo ./ext4fuse /dev/disk0s3 ~/Mountpoint
```

or

```
sudo ./ext4fuse /dev/rdisk0s3 ~/Mountpoint
```

(I'm not sure what's the difference between disk and rdisk)

but I just end up with an unusable shortcut. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

I always use the first form, although without sudo (as long as you are in the admin group it should work).

You can optionally pass a third parameter to use a log file.  That might shed some light in the issue:

```
mbpro:~ gerard$ ./Development/ext4fuse/ext4fuse /dev/disk0s5 t log
mbpro:~ gerard$ ls t
gerard      lost+found
```

The file "log" should now contain some debugging info.  Send it to me (gerard.lledo@gmail.com), create a issue in github or simply post it here.

Get sure you are using at least OSX 10.5 with intel (ppc won't work).  Also, I've only tested this with native ext4 partitions (no ext3 to ext4 upgrades), so it might give you problems if you have the later scenario.

**Edit:** As of June 21st, 2017, the syntax for getting a log file is:

```
ext4fuse <device> <mountpoint> -o logfile=/dev/stdout
```

Comment: Do you need Macfuse 2.1.5 beta or can ext4fuse be used with 2.0.3?

Answer (score 1):

try fuse-ext2

Install mac-fuse google it.
and get http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/fuse-ext2/fuse-ext2-0.0.7.tar.gz?download
and install.

I've tested and work 100% in ext4 partition in MACOSX 10.6.7,
a trick, to be read and save, use the command fuse-ext2 /dev/disk0sX /Volumes/linux -o force
or reboot macosx before installation and auto mount ext4 in macosx.

Comment: this should be the best answer. ext4fuse doesn't even allow you to write to disk. but fuse-ext2 works perfectly. remember to use macfuse v 2.1.7, not 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The issue was raised [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/25565)

There are some links there, it seems that in some cases the compatibility layer does not get installed. I will further investigate.

Try a USB card reader with Linux VM as a last resort, that worked for me.